# Como criar um Android App Bundle no terminal?

Tags: android, android-studio, bundle

1) Criar e assinar os APKs android pelo terminal sempre foi relativamente facil. Mas agora com a nova forma "bundle" estou apanhando bastante.

hoje eu uso o seguinte:

> cordova build android --release

crio a chave, e depois:

> jarsigner
>   zipalign...

e assim eu crio o APK...

2) Mas para a parte de transformar em .AAB,  tenho procurado na net onde achei muita coisa pela metade ou que nao funciona, 
[MindOrks](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-app-bundle-part-2-bundletool-6705b50bea4c), [SO eng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

Por exemplo tenho procurado instalar esse **"gradlew"**  mas ninguém fala sobre sua instalação e uso. Somente que eh preciso.
trocando em miudos depois de duas semanas estou totalmente perdida...

ou seja minha pergunta eh:
**Como criar um Android App Bundle no terminal ?**

obrigada.

Comment: achei a resposta... em outro forum... devo apagar este post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar o "app bundle" pela linha de comando, quando usando o cordova por exemplo, basta ir na pasta onde o cordova criou a "platform".

*No meu caso fica em:*

/User/camila/projetos/MyApp/platforms/android

**1)** Então, execute o gradelw que esta nesta pasta, para criar o .aab !!!
simples assim!
ou seja:

> ./gradlew bundleRelease

(**lembre-se 1**: como eu uso cordova, para que o gradlew seja corretamente configurado, eh preciso rodar o comando "cordova build android", pelo menos uma vez)

(**lembre-se 2**: no iMac o gradlew  tem que ter o atributo de execução/programa)

(**lembre-se 3**: isso também ja assina o pacote, ou seja, nao eh mais preciso criar uma chave de assinatura com o "jarsigner"!!)

**PRONTO** pegue seu arquivo .aab em:
/User/camila/projetos/MyApp/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab

*e coloque na sua pasta preferida.*

**2)** Gostaria apenas de comentar um ponto importante: **para poder enviar para a google** eh preciso usar o zipalign

> zipalign -f -v 4  app-release.aab MyApp-release.aab

*ou seja, para a solução completa, sao apenas 2 comandos no terminal!*

Comment: O `zipalign` é desnecessário caso você configure o gradle para assinar o app com o `signingConfigs`: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#gradle_signing

Comment: realmente.... o zipalign... eh """"desnecessario""""....   mas...  tambem da mais trabalho ficar editando o tal arquivo citado...  fica mais burocratico. LEMBRE-SE tambem que se, voce remover aquela plartaforma (no caso o android), quando cria-la de novo devera editar o arquivo novamente.